# provide() function in Angular2 RC6 removed...need to found a walkarround to use similar functionality

Tags: angular

I have the following code I get from book Mastering Angular 2 Components but is not compatible with Angular 2 RC. provide() function is not anymore a member of angular/core. I need this code to work:

```
const providers = [
              **provide(PluginData, {
                useValue: pluginData
              }**)
            ];   

// We're creating a new child injector and provide the PluginData provider       
const childInjector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate(providers,contextInjector);
```

How could I replace it so it could be functional?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this:

```
const providers = [ { provide: PluginData, { useValue: pluginData } }];
```